# Как стилизовать радиокнопки согласно дизайну?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Есть переключатель да-нет, который хочу стилизовать согласно дизайну
[image: картинка]

но пока не получается, [вот наработки в фидле](https://jsfiddle.net/93b8vbcb/1/)

```js
$('input').styler();
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #964939;
  color: white;
}
.jq-radio {
  width: 28px;
  height: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted white;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.jq-radio~span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 6px;
}
.jq-radio.checked {
  width: 64px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.jq-radio.checked~span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 22px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 204px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #ffd900;
  color: #231f20;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0;
}
.jq-radio .jq-radio__div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://dimox.github.io/jQueryFormStyler/jquery.formstyler.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dimox.github.io/jQueryFormStyler/jquery.formstyler.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    <input name="answer" class="styler" type="radio" value="yes">Да
    <input name="answer" class="styler" type="radio" value="no" checked>Нет</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну насколько мне известно, такие вещи делаются следующим образом:  
Каждому инпуту привязывается `label`, инпут прячется, а `label` стилизуется как необходимо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вот на css:

```css
/* Базовые стили */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #964939;
}

/* Cкрываем input[type="radio"] */
.radio {
  display: none;
}

/* Стили для кнопок */
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;  
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

/* dotted подчеркивание */
.btn:after {
  content: '....';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
/* Обертка для кнопок */
.list {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Перемещающийся блок */
.list:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
/* "Да" */
#on:checked~.list:after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

#on:checked~.list .btn_on:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* "Нет" */
#off:checked~.list:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
#off:checked~.list .btn_off:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="r" class="radio" id="on" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="r" class="radio" id="off">
  
  <div class="list">
    <label class="btn btn_on" for="on">Да</label><label class="btn btn_off" for="off">Нет</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: а в передаче формы как-то определиться какой вариант выбран? просто в коде я вижу, что положение `checked` в `input` не изменяется..

Comment: @Вася, закомментируйте строки `.radio {
  display: none;
}` и убедитесь, что все меняется!

Comment: а для плагина `contact form 7` за счет доп оберток такой финт уже провернуться не удастся?
https://jsfiddle.net/vqq64ybv/

Comment: @Вася, я бы Вам посоветовала отдельным вопросом это задать. contact form 7, если не ошибаюсь, генерирует свою форму. С ней чуточку проблематичнее будет.

Comment: опубликовал здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584871/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-radio-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-contact-form-wordpress

Answer (score 7):

Както так?

```css
div{
  background-color:   #964939;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
.radio{ 
  display: none;  
}

.radio + label{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: none;
}

.radio + label > span{
    border-bottom: 5px dotted;
    padding-left: 3px; /*add more dots*/
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.radio:checked + label{ /*add round border*/
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.radio:checked + label > span{
    border-bottom: none ; /*remove dots*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  <input name="answer" class="radio" type="radio" value="yes" id="yes"><label for="yes"><span>Да</span></label>
  <input name="answer" class="radio" type="radio" value="no" id="no" checked/><label for="no"><span> Нет</span></label>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на простоту и главное отсутствие ненужных раздражающих свисто-перделок в виде анимации медленного переползания рамочки.