# Как стилизовать radio кнопку в contact form wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

[В продолжение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583871/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%83/583884?noredirect=1#comment779373_583884) по стилизации радио кнопок с которым удалось успешно справиться, теперь есть необходимость адаптировать их для формы [contact form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) в `wordpress`, где уже другая обертка, повлиять на которую нельзя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописываю так:

```
[radio gates-avto id:on class:radio default:1 "Да"]
[radio gates-avto id:on class:radio "Нет"]
<div class="list">
<label class="btn btn_on" for="on">Да</label><label class="btn btn_off" for="off">Нет</label>
</div>
```

Получаю следующее - [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/vqq64ybv/)

```css
/* Базовые стили */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #964939;
}
/* Cкрываем input[type="radio"] */

.radio {
  display: none;
}
/* Стили для кнопок */

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
/* dotted подчеркивание */

.btn:after {
  content: '....';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
/* Обертка для кнопок */

.list {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Перемещающийся блок */

.list:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
/* "Да" */

#on:checked~.list:after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
#on:checked~.list .btn_on:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* "Нет" */

#off:checked~.list:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
#off:checked~.list .btn_off:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="r" class="radio" id="on" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="r" class="radio" id="off">

  <div class="list">
    <label class="btn btn_on" for="on">Да</label>
    <label class="btn btn_off" for="off">Нет</label>
  </div>
</form>

<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap gates-avto"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio radio" id="on"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><input type="radio" name="gates-avto" value="Да" checked="checked">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Да</span></span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap gates-avto"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio radio" id="off"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><input type="radio" name="gates-avto" value="Нет">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Нет</span></span>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
<div class="list">
  <label class="btn btn_on" for="on">Да</label>
  <label class="btn btn_off" for="off">Нет</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой такой вариант (не думаю, что идеален, возможно кто-то напишет лучше):

```js
var 
yes         = $('#on').find('input'),
no          = $('#off').find('input'),
labelForYes = yes.next('.wpcf7-list-item-label'),
labelForNo  = no.next('.wpcf7-list-item-label'),
wrap        = yes.closest('p'),
inputs      = wrap.find('[type="radio"]');

wrap.addClass('list');
wrap.find('br').hide();
inputs.hide();

var list = $('.list');

labelForYes.on('click', function(){
  no.prop( "checked", false);
  yes.prop( "checked", true);
  
  list.removeClass('off').addClass('on');
});

labelForNo.on('click', function(){
  yes.prop( "checked", false);
  no.prop( "checked", true);
  
  list.removeClass('on').addClass('off');
});
```

```css
/* Базовые стили */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #964939;
}

/* Доп.стили для <p>  обертки*/
.list span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap{
  float:left;
}

/* Стили для кнопок */
span.wpcf7-list-item-label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
/* dotted подчеркивание */
.wpcf7-list-item-label:after {
  content: '....';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
/* Обертка для кнопок */
.list {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}
/* Перемещающийся блок */
.list:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
/* "Да" */
.on.list:after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
/* "Нет" */
.off.list:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

/* Убираем подчеркивание */
input:checked+span.wpcf7-list-item-label:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  
<p>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap gates-avto">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio radio" id="on">
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
        <input type="radio" name="gates-avto" value="Да" checked="checked">
        &nbsp;
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Да</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap gates-avto">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio radio" id="off">
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
        <input type="radio" name="gates-avto" value="Нет">
        &nbsp;
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Нет</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```